# Why do aeron publication image positions take part in flow control during the linger state?

Tags: aeron

When a untethered subscription falls behind, after untethered window limit timeout in the bottom 1/4 of the receive window it will transition to the linger state, it will then spend another period of time (untethered window limit timeout again) before transitioning to the resting state. During this time it still takes part in local flow control.

What is the benefit of this lagging subscription from continuing to take part in local flow control?

I'd expect it makes sense to immediately move the subscription into the resting state, as it doesn't seem like it can recover from the linger state in any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a delay between a subscription falling outside the window and the unavailable image notification reaching the client and then being acted on. The linger prevents the image being aggressively progressed which has the potential for corrupting of the log buffer data structure. It is a similar protection to why the image in the driver has a linger state.

Comment: Thanks I think this mostly makes sense to me, it seems like an impossible problem to solve perfectly.

I assume if you removed the slow subscriber from flow control immediately the log buffer would be safe for all other subscribers, and only potentially "corrupt" for the now resting (although unaware) subscriber.
Is that correct? Or can the log buffer somehow become corrupted from all view points?

Comment: The issue is the lingering subscription which is likely slow or de-scheduled. You don't want the log advancing, and possibly wrapping, before the lingering subscriber stops reading. We need to feel reasonably confident the unavailable notification has been acted on before progressing.

Comment: Would it make sense for the slow subscriber to acknowledge the unavailable notification? You'd then be able to cut the linger state short, and be able to confidently error if the timeout is exceeded and no acknowledgement has been received.
I see two benefits of this, lower impact on other subscribers, and better visibility in the off chance something really is slow enough that its reading corrupt data.

Comment: The client conductor thread could ack but this is not sufficient. The subscriber thread needs to ack and the acking may add additional complexity that could reduce performance. Timeouts are still required for bad clients so this would add complexity that cannot be offset. It may be possible but we prioritise our commercial clients.